# Segmentation fault with char pointer

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I tried to run a piece of code on windows, and the same one on Linux.
While it ran fine on windows, it gave me a segmentation fault in linux. I know in this code my allocated memory is getting wasted, but can someone please clarify why linux is giving a fault while windows is not.

```
char *ptr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(2*10));
ptr="harsh";
printf("%s\n",ptr);
```

Comment: I don't see any problems other than the memory leak in this code, but do not do `free(ptr);` after `ptr="harsh";`.

Comment: plz post the whole program code

Comment: You allocate size of `int` . Why ?

Comment: @ameyCU At where? `int`'s size is not always 2 bytes.

Comment: @MikeCAT `sizeof(2*10)`  what is it suppose to give ?

Comment: @ameyCU Sorry. It will be same value as `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: In C it is not possible to assign an array, nor to copy-on-assign an array. Assigning an array to a pointer sets the pointer to the address of the array's 1st element.

Comment: You really should tell us *which* line of code triggers the crash. This is not a guessing game.

Comment: ... as the three lines shown on themselves won't provoke a crash, not even the infamous Undefined Behaviour. They are just leaking 20 bytes of memory.

Comment: @ameyCU is absolutely correct. I was actually allocating memory equal to sizeof(int), it should rather be malloc(2*10). Really sorry for the delay, I was just going through this question and realized my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't segfault all by itself.  Most likely there is a bug somewhere else that is overwriting the memory used by the string "harsh" (so printf will crash) or overwriting the data structures that maintain the heap (so malloc will crash)

These kinds of problems are common with beginning programmers, and cause different problems in different environments.  Since 2 out of 3 lines in this program seem to have memory-related bugs, it seems likely.

One of the most important things a C++ programmer has to learn is to be very afraid of these kinds of bugs.  That's why, in modern C++, we ALWAYS use RAII and collection classes to make sure these kinds of problems don't happen.

Comment: "*... C++ programmer ...*" this is a C question, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, so it is...  C programmers, unfortunately, don't have those kinds of tools available and must be vigilant all the time.